# Production does'nt work ( Rails 5 , Passenger , Nginx )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

I deployed my app to server. ( Rails 5 , Passenger , Nginx ) 
My app was working on development mode. 
But i changed my mode to production and it i got this error ( /var/log/nginx/error.log ) :

```
[ E 2017-11-10 20:11:03.9343 21613/Tb age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/rails/myapp: An error occurred while starting up predloader
  Error ID: ca909334
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-iGQLnf.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- /home/rails/myapp/config/environment (LoadError)
  config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

After this error i switched my mode to development. And i got same error again !

my nginx file :

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
   access_log off;
   return 301 https://www.myapp.com$request_uri;
}

server {

  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/myapp.com/ssl-bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myapp.key;

  server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  root /home/rails/myapp/public;
  index index.html index.htm;

}
```

Need help to solve this problem !

Comment: can you add the configuration of passenger and content of error details saved in /tmp/passenger-error-iGQLnf.html

Comment: i added /tmp/passenger-error-iGQLnf.html

Comment: In all the files, your app name is 'myapp' where as in passenger-eoor-iGQLnf.html , your app name is shown as 'trbodybuilding'. Can you explain this ? 
Also add the content of configuration file of passenger.

Comment: check if there is a conf file in /etc/nginx/passenger.conf or not?

Comment: `passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby; ` -> Passenger.conf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158728/discussion-between-yalin-semer-and-aakash-gupta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turned out that the problem was due to incorrect file permissions for the user.

Nginx was being run as www-data user which didn't have permissions to read files of the app-directory.
That is why booting of app-server was failing.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/rails/myapp
```

After using above command, passenger will be able to read the files of app-directory and will successfully start.